# How to stop overwriting first index in an array

Tags: php, arrays, json, function, array-push

I'm having a problem pushing more than one comment to an array

When I submit a comment it overwrites the previous one

```php
include "includes/globals_constants.php"; 

$comments = [];

if (isset($_POST["commentSubmit"])) {

    setComment($comments);

}

function setComment($data) {

    $comment = htmlspecialchars($_POST["comment"]);
    $blogitem = [
        "comment" => $comment
    ];

    array_push($data, $blogitem);

    if (file_put_contents(DBCOMMENTS, json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: From the [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) doc: "Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set."

Comment: It overwrites where? In file? So, do `file_put_contents(DBCOMMENTS, json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND)`.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Which parts of that code are responsible for overwriting something?

Answer (score 1):

You need your argument to be a reference to the original array, if you want to mutate the latter inside the function. If you don't pass it by reference the original array isn't mutated and the copy into which you put your comment is lost since you don't return it.

**Code:**

```
function setComment (&$data) {...}
```

Answer (score -1):

A guess: Replace

```
array_push($data, $blogitem);
```

with

```
global $comments;
array_push($comments, $blogitem);
```

A question: Is this encapsulation necessary?

```
$blogitem = [ "comment" => $comment ];
```